# ClickOnce permission issue

Tags: c#, windows-10, certificate, clickonce

I've been tasked with converting a ClickOnce application from Windows 7 to Windows 10. It hasn't been significantly touched in several years. The developer who wrote it is long gone.

I had to upgrade Visual Studio from 2008 to 2017. This appears to be successful - I can build the app and deploy. They sign using the test certificate.

On Windows 7, this all works as expected.

On Windows 10, running setup.exe appears to work: In the deployment folder I see:

- Application Files/ folder
- app-manifest
- setup.exe

and the application comes up and seems to work when launched from setup.exe. (Can't tell for sure - need other hardware to work with Windows10 first - not my problem...) but what I *can* run at least doesn't crash.

When double clicking on the app-manifest we get:

> Function = Form1_Load had unhandled exception= System Exception Error. This
>   program doesn't have the access it needs to run. Please change the setting at
>   'Control Panel/UserAccouts/Change user AccountControl Setting' to the
>   lowest setting. Without this change, this program will not run.

Tried that, no joy.

Another stackoverflow answer led me to try adding the certificate to Trusted Root Certification Authorities and Trusted Publisher.

I *think* I did that successfully, but no change. I'm tearing out what little hair I have left!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was not a certificate issue. The exception message was actually thrown by the application if any exception was caught, masking the current cause of the error. Classic blunder by a junior engineer. Sigh... At least I get paid by the hour.